# Zero-Inflated count data needed for regression assignment

Tags: regression

I am looking for a data-set for my stats 3 assignment. I need a zero-inflated count response and at least 2 predictors in order to fit a Poisson, ZIP, ZINB and a HURDLE model etc. I am not allowed to use in-built R data-sets.

I have looked through many library resources, but have not found data that is suitable. If there is any data-set that someone could recommend, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Count data refers to the data containing a count of event data. 
You could use lot of data in that area.

Have you tried. https://data.world/datasets/count

Crime Statistics are also very common count data.

This is also very helpful link. https://www.ucrdatatool.gov/